# Emiting events from JS and catching them in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt4

I'm trying to make a movable window without actually creating any widgets (except a `QWebView`) and I'm wondering if is possible to emit `QMouseEvent` from JavaScript (inside `QWebView`) and catch the signal with C++?

I'm already aware how to call C++ methods from JS (and vice-versa) as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) but I'm asking if I'll be able to generate/emit an event containing a `QMouseEvent` (that's really important because of the current global position of the cursor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't that hard after all.

First of all, I exposed my window to the JavaScript engine:

```cpp
this->webView()->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("CHtml5ApplicationViewer", this);
```

Then I created a simple div inside my HTML code and attached this code to handle the mouse onClick, onMove and onDrag events.

```js
document.getElementById("bar").onmousedown = function(e){

    CHtml5ApplicationViewer.fakeMousePressEvent(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    e.preventDefault();

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
        CHtml5ApplicationViewer.fakeMouseMoveEvent(e.screenX, e.screenY);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    this.onmouseup = function(){
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }

    document.getElementById("bar").ondragstart = function() { return false; }
}
```

Finally, I added two functions in my C++ code that will handle the calls from my JavaScript code:

```cpp
void CHtml5ApplicationViewer::fakeMousePressEvent(int fromBorderX, int fromBorderY){
    fromBorderPosition = QPoint(fromBorderX, fromBorderY);
}

void CHtml5ApplicationViewer::fakeMouseMoveEvent(int dragX, int dragY){
    move(QPoint(dragX, dragY) - fromBorderPosition);
}
```

Also, make sure that you make those functions callable from JS!

```cpp
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void fakeMousePressEvent(int fromBorderX, int fromBorderY);
    Q_INVOKABLE void fakeMouseMoveEvent(int dragX, int dragY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you can not do that since cpp is residing in another memory than the javascript running. However I have no idea what those tools are and how they are set up.

The usual way of dealing with those issues is to make some kind of "neutral" middle layer/communication channel by just sending strings/xml/json-objects or your own "script language". If you automate this process it would usually be called "serializing an object" which means converting it to some kind of format that you can either store on disk and rebuild later or convert it into "plain text" that some other tool can read and understand. An object resides in memory and as long as you don't share memory between the applications there is no way that they can understand what is happening.

For instance with your own "script language" always do calls through custom function `notifyCPP(header, parameter)` where an example would be `notifyCPP("MOUSE_POSITION_UPDATE", "x=189; y=200");`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but you really have no idea what I asked, do you?

Comment: That is true, it sure sounded like passing the actual element of QMouseEvent from JS to CPP though, sorry if it wasn't appropriate to guess on my part.

Comment: There's a link in my question which describes really well how to call C++ methods from JS (and vice-versa), and besides that I already said I know how this is done. The difficulty here is generating a QMouseEvent that contains the cursor position in the moment the event was generated.

Comment: Read the article and googled some more, still doesn't understand what it is you want to do in the end. But, maybe these posts might help you:

"http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3073-How-to-get-mouse-s-position"

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178938/finding-current-mouse-position-in-qt"

Comment: I just found a solution to what I was looking for. If you were wondering how/what was I asking exactly, please have a look.